# Data structure supporting the following operations

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure for working with a set of data which is most efficient to do the following :

1. Check whether an item has been categorized or not. (The categorized and uncategorized set are disjoint sets).
2. Get the category of an item.
3. Get all the items in a particular category.
4. Get all the uncategorized items.
5. Remove a particular item from the data set.

I was thinking of having a `Dictionary<String, Set<String>>` to hold all the items in a given category, but that doesn't solve 2.

Comment: If it is ML or a related language in which you would code this data structure, you could use SOME (category name) or NONE in the place of String.  Could you otherwise use a null string to indicate uncategorized information?

Comment: Do you want to make a relational database?

Answer (score 2):

You tried to model “`Category` *has-many* `Item`”. However, your requirements state that the relationship is bidirectional. I would therefore start with “`Item` *has-one-or-none* `Category`”. Requirements 1,2,5 can be fulfilled with the following design:

```java
enum Category { FOO, BAR }

class Item {
  private Category category;

  // Req 1
  public boolean  isCategorized()           { return category != null; }
  // Req 2
  public Category getCategory()             { return category; }
  // Req 5
  public void     removeCategory()          { category = null; }
}
```

This representation of categories is not sufficient, because requirements 3 and 4 are not fulfilled. For that, we need a reference back from each Category to each Item.

```java
enum Category {
  NONE, FOO, BAR;

  private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

  // Reqs 3, 4
  public Iterable<Item> items() { return items; }

  // only to be called by Item
  boolean add   (Item item) { return items.add(item);    }
  boolean remove(Item item) { return items.remove(item); }
}

class Item {
  private Category category;

  public Item(Category cat) { setCategory(cat != null ? cat : Category.NONE); }

  // Req 1
  public boolean isCategorized() { return !category.equals(Category.NONE); }
  // Req 2
  public Category getCategory()  { return category; }
  // Req 5
  public void removeCategory() {
    setCategory(Category.EMPTY)
  }

  private void setCategory(Category cat) {
    if (category != null && !category.remove(this)) throw SomeException ...;
    if (!cat.add(this)) throw SomeException ...;
    category = cat;
  }
}
```

Notice that `Item` is solely responsible for maintaining referential integrity. Because every `Item` has a non-null `category` where it is registered, we can obtain all “uncategorized” items via `Category.NONE.items()`.